# Mysql - Search multiple keyword with single string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got problem how to implement this search method. How to implement multiple keyword inside table column with single message?

My current sql query

```
SELECT *FROM rules WHERE keyword LIKE '%$message%'
```

Sample data inside `keyword` column for table `rules` (a string that has multiple comma separated keywords in it):

```
ASK, QUESTION
```

Sample message:

```
I want to ask and question for this thing
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Consider using full text indexing.

Comment: so the keyword column is a string that has multiple comma separated keywords in it?  or are the two shown keywords from 2 different rows?

Comment: yes,a string that has multiple comma separated keywords in it

Comment: with that architecture I'm not sure if you come around using a procedure or the like. If keyword on the other hand was in its own table ruleKeywords (rules_id, keyword) with 1 keyword per entry there it would be possible to do the whole thing in 1 single sql statement

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is the opposite of full-text indexing. The search words are in the table, the text to search comes from the client.

Comment: @Barmar . . . You can search for a longer search string than the keywords itself.  Of course, you wouldn't want to set it up as a boolean search with and.  Probably a better solution is to parse the string before passing it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to split up a comma-delimited string in MySQL -- you'd have to write a stored procedure with a loop in it.

Instead, consider normalizing the `rules` table, with each keyword in a different row:

```
CREATE TABLE rule_keywords (
    rule_id INT,
    keyword VARCHAR(30),
    UNIQUE INDEX (keyword, rule_id)
);
```

This query will tell you all the rules where **any** of the keywords match the message.

```
SELECT DISTINCT rule_id
FROM rule_keywords
WHERE '$message' LIKE CONCAT('%', keyword, '%');
```

If you want to find rules where **all* of the keywords match, you can do:

```
SELECT rule_id, SUM('$message' LIKE CONCAT('%', keyword, '%')) AS num_matches,
                COUNT(*) AS num_keywords
FROM rule_keywords
HAVING num_matches = num_keywords
```

In either case, you can then join this with the `rules` table to get other information about the rules that were matched.

Comment: that was exactly what I had in mind with my comment^^. in this case as he also wants the rules it would be a join with rules necessary there still

Answer (score 1):

I fully support Barmars suggestion to normalising your tables.

However with your relatively simple test data it is possible to do what you want (although probably not advisable) assuming the words are separated with a constant (such as a space) in a single query.

The following copes with search phrases of up to 100 words.

```
SELECT rules_id, COUNT(*) AS keyword_match_count, GROUP_CONCAT(message_word)
FROM rules
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, ' ', anInt), ' ', -1) AS message_word
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 'I want to ask and question for this thing' AS message
    ) sub1
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT units.i + tens.i * 10 + 1 AS anInt
        FROM
        (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units,
        (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
    ) sub2
) sub3
ON FIND_IN_SET(message_word, rules.keyword)
GROUP BY rules_id
ORDER BY keyword_match_count DESC
```

SQL fiddle for it here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7678fa/2